# Unable to connect to QC server

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center

I am a .NET developer using C#. I am trying to connect to QC Version 11 server (64bit)  but it's throwing an exception (Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))) when I call .InitConnectionEx  method. I have installed QC client 11 on my development machine. My development machine is also 64 bit (Windows 7/2008).  It looks like some QC dll is not getting registered during client installation on the local machine. I have written the below C# code for connection but I am receiving the issue on line 2.

```
TDConnection tdConnect = new TDConnection();
tdConnect.InitConnectionEx("http://192.168.1.10:8181/qcbin/");
tdConnect.ConnectProjectEx("DEFAULT", "Test", "admin", "admin");
```

Please help me to find out solution on priority.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your application with elevated privileges? It could be the application is not able to access the appropriate underlying COM object the .NET wrapper is trying to access...

Comment: No, if I connect same QC server (64 bit) from 32bit client machine (development machine) then there is no such issue. I am facing this issue when I am running my application on 64bit machine.

Comment: It's most likely due to the COM components being used not being written for 64-bit. I would probably recommend forcing your app to run as a 32-bit app even when deployed to a 64-bit machine. There is a setting in VisualStudio to accomplish this when you build.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the QC Connectivity Add in, I believe it registers all the components correctly and fixed this error for me.

11.52 and possibly other versions: from within QC Explorer > Help > ALM Tools > HP ALM Connectivity

QC 11: https://almpc.sqa.its.state.nc.us/qcbin/TDConnectivity_index.html

*If the quality center server was patched, you may have to login to QC and then copy all of the files from your appdata/local\HP\ALM-Client\alm folder into C:\ProgramData\HP\ALM-Client\alm